# Spring Java Inheritance not working with lombok

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka, lombok

In inheritance, I'm not getting the Child class properties. Code is shown below

```
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode
Class Employee {
private String fName;
private String lName;
private Account account;
}
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode
Class Account {
private accountNo;
}
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode
Class SavingAccount extends Account{
private balance
}
@Setter
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@SuperBuilder
@EqualsAndHashCode
class CurrentAccount extends Account{
private balance;
}
```

At runtime can get any type of account and will set it into Employee and its correctly happening but the same object goes to `Kafka` topic and another consumer consumes it there I am getting Employee & Account properties not subclass of account. May be something is wrong with `Lombok` annotations. Please help

Comment: You know that you can use `@Data` right?

Comment: `@Data` is like having implicit `@Getter, @Setter, @ToString, @EqualsAndHashCode and @RequiredArgsConstructor` annotations on the class (except that no constructor will be generated if any explicitly written constructors already exist).

Comment: @Ganesh are you using any IDE

Comment: So remove all that tags and replace it with `@Data`. It is equivalent to what you have

Comment: @TechGeek49 - thanks but if Data is combination of all the given then will it make difference.. please help me to understand what's the issue that not getting subclass fields.

Comment: Your code is full of typos and doesn't even come close to compiling. Please fix this, otherwise we won't be able to help you.